# How to reference column names that start with a number, in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If the column names in `data.table` are in the form of `number + character`, for example: `4PCS`, `5Y` etc, how could this be referenced as `j` in `x[i,j]` so that it is interpreted as an unquoted column name.

I assume this would solve mine original problem. I wanted to add several column in 'data.table' which were in the form `number + character`.

```
M <- data.table('4PCS'=1:4,'5Y'=4:1,X5Y=2:5)
> M[,4PCS+5Y]
Error: unexpected symbol in "M[,4PCS"
```

The new column should be a sum of `4PSC` and `5Y`.

Is there a way how to refer to them in `data.table` in no quoted form? If these columns are referred in `data.table` with the quoted "logic" of `data.frame` :

```
> M[,'5Y',with=FALSE]
     5Y
[1,]  4
[2,]  3
[3,]  2
[4,]  1
```

then there will be a limitation in functionality of such reference. The addition would not work as it does not work in `data.frame`:

```
> M[,'4PCS'+'5Y',with=FALSE]  
Error in "4PCS" + "5Y" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The `data.table` functionality would allow to operate over the columns. I would like to find a solution in the new `data.table` logic hence I can use its ability to transform the columns by *column name referencing*.

The question is:
How to *quote* the column name which start with number so that the data.table logic would understand that it is a column name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think, this is what you're looking for, not sure. `data.table` is *different* from `data.frame`. Please have a look at the [**quick introduction**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf), and then the [**FAQ**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf) (and also the reference manual if necessary).

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table("4PCS" = 1:3, y=3:1)
#    4PCS y
# 1:    1 3
# 2:    2 2
# 3:    3 1

# access column 4PCS
dt[, "4PCS"]

# returns a data.table
#    4PCS
# 1:    1
# 2:    2
# 3:    3

# to access multiple columns by name
dt[, c("4PCS", "y")]
```

Alternatively, if you need to access the column and *not* result in a `data.table`, rather a vector, then you can access using the `$` notation:

```
dt$`4PCS` # notice the ` because the variable begins with a number
# [1] 1 2 3

# alternatively, as mnel mentioned under comments:
dt[, `4PCS`] 
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or if you know the column number you can access using `[[.]]` as follows:

```
dt[[1]] # 4PCS is the first column here
# [1] 1 2 3
```

---

**Edit:**

Thanks @joran. I think you're looking for this:

```
dt[, `4PCS` + y]
# [1] 4 4 4
```

Fundamentally the issue is that `4CPS` is not a valid variable name in R (try `4CPS <- 1`, you'll get the same "Unexpected symbol" error). So to refer to it, we have to use backticks (compare`` `4CPS` <- 1 ``)

Comment: don't forget ``dt[, `4PCS`]`` (back ticking `4PCS`, as you would normally do outside data.table

Comment: then make it clear that column name should not start with number

Answer (score 0):

You can also put an 'X' immediately before the variable name you are calling to get R to recognise it as a name rather than evaluating the number and the string as different (and hence bad syntax)

So e.g. when calling 4PCS use X4PCS

as in

mydata <- X4PCS