# R dplyr filter column with column name that starts with number

Tags: r, dplyr

*Edit: a near-duplicate*
[How to reference column names that start with a number, in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637132/how-to-reference-column-names-that-start-with-a-number-in-data-table)
*The post above regards `data.table`. The problem is similar but technically package-dependent, but the solution is the same*.

*Start of original post*

I'm unable to figure out how to filter the following column with `dplyr::filter`

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1)) %>%
        setNames(c(paste0("1", letters[1])))
      # 1a
# 1   TRUE
# 2   TRUE
# 3  FALSE
# 4  FALSE
# 5   TRUE
# 6  FALSE
# 7  FALSE
# 8  FALSE
# 9  FALSE
# 10  TRUE

df[df$"1a"==TRUE,]
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

df %>% dplyr::filter("1a"==TRUE)
# [1] 1a
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Use `df %>% dplyr::filter(\`1a\` == TRUE)`

Comment: It doesn't really matter that it's a column name. Any non-standard variable (or column) name can be used with backticks. `\`1a\` = 4; \`1a\` + 1`

Comment: Appreciate the help! If you'd like to post as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: Different question because it's about `data.table`, but the backticks are also covered in [How to reference column names that start with a number, in `data.table`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15637132/903061) (also probably good to link to such a closely related question.

Comment: @Gregor yes, definitely a duplicate. Added link to my post

Comment: See also `?Quotes`. The 'Names and Identifiers' section is especially relevant here: "other [syntactically invalid] names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick"

Comment: I would say *related* but not a duplicate. The other one is `data.table`-specific, and this one is `dplyr`-specific. I think this one should get an answer and remain separate but linked. There are definitely people who will search for `dplyr` or `data.table`-specific answers for this and be confused if they don't find them.

Comment: _Related_ on `select`ing syntactically invalid names: [dplyr: select column names containing white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842232/dplyr-select-column-names-containing-white-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backticks to refer to variables with non-standard names. This works whether they are columns of a data frame or not.

For this specific case

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(`1a`)  # note that == TRUE is never needed
```

Or generally,

```
`2b` = 1:5
mean(`2b`)
# [1] 3
```

Of course you shouldn't make a bad habit of this - use standard names whenever possible.

---

As mentioned in comments, the `?Quotes` documentation is helpful. It states (in the *Names and Identifiers* section):

> Almost always, other names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and `deparse` will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit variable names in formulae: see `formula`.